# Change Emacs color theme based on extension of open file

Tags: emacs, themes

emacs have different color theme; I can chose one when it starts up by setting the right color theme in my .emacs file or change it later using M-x.

But I want to let emacs chose the color theme automatically when I open a file.

For example, when the open file is a *.py, use color theme A, but when the open file is a *.c file, use color theme B.

Could i do it?  Does it require lisp programming? (I have no skill in lisp programming.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is syntax highlighting per mode (font-lock in Emacs speak) not sufficient? Why do you want to change the colour theme?

Answer (score 0):

```
 (defun c-mode-theme-hook ()
  (require 'color-theme)
  (color-theme-initialize)
  (color-theme-gray30))

 (add-hook 'c-mode-hook
   'c-mode-theme-hook)
```

Something like this code should add gray30 color theme when Emacs enters c-mode.  You might have to write these things for each mode you want a color-theme.

So, you could do it.  It does not require lisp programming.

Comment: @Thomas  It is.  I have seen it in many .emacs files so I think someone with no elisp programming skills should easily be able to pick up.

Comment: @Thomas I mean, similar constructs.  This piece of code here, I made up myself though

Comment: This code, however, will change the theme in all buffers, so if you open an c buffer, then a python buffer, the c buffer will naturally be affected as well.

Comment: @Bozhidar Batsov my elisp skill is limited, as is evident from the code.  Can you perhaps post a better working code, notwithstanding the comment from the OP?  I will be glad to have learnt something.

Comment: package color-theme is obsolete as of 2019